# Network icon not visible in Ubuntu 12.04, how to get it back?

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, icons

When I tried to configure a broadband connection in my Ubuntu 12.04 somehow the network icon has been removed from the system panel. I tried many kinds of solutions but still it is not visible. Now I am unable to add new connections.

How can I get the icon back?

Comment: If you tried "many kinds of solutions", always enumerate them, so they do not get proposed again.

Comment: Did you tried this `sudo apt-get purge network-manager-gnome && sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome`

Answer (score 0):

Can you perform that ?

http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-a-Network-in-Ubuntu

Else, you can set up a network with command lines :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic